# MongoDB - count current read/write operations

Tags: replication, mongodb

is it possible to count the current read or write operations on a mongodb replica set? (including all databases not just a single database)

Thank you!

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

The [serverStatus](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/index.html#serverstatus) command contains [operation counts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/index.html#opcounters), which report on database operations by type since the mongod instance last started.

If you need to find the number of operations over a specific time period, retrieve the serverStatus result periodically for comparison over time.